# How to delete extra DIV element from HTML Document

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a News application and for this i am using a web product for fetching News Headline. When I call a NewsHeadline, product sends a Html Code including News Headline.

```
<div class="mydiv">


<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write('&lt;div style="display: none"&gt;');
</script><div style="display: none;">

<div>< a href="http:// www.abc.com.au/ news_manager/default.aspx ?z=41">Main News Item 6</a>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write('&lt;/div&gt;');
</script></div>

<script src="http://www.abc.com/news_manager/ajaxzone.aspx?z=41&amp;pz=125&amp;h=1&amp;sort=startdate&amp;ord=desc&amp;xlaparsing=true" language="javascript"></script><div id="xlaANMzone_928960"><div class="" id="928960"><h5>
  <a href="http://www.mysite.com/article.asp?a=1144&amp;Z=41">
     test article from anil
  </a>
</h5>
</div>
[red]<div align="left"></div>[/red]
</div>

</div>
```

The Newsproduct is sending an extra div ie () on the lower end of above code( written withing [Red] block). and this div is taking extra space in IE 6, and 7 only. its working fine in OPera,FF and Safari.

So what I need is to DELETE this extra div either on document ready or on load event. I used some scripts not worked for me. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Following code removes all empty divs from document

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
  var div = divs[i];
  if(div.innerHTML=="") div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

..If you have a trim function, you could use innerHTML.trim() where necessary...

..It should be run at onload

Comment: @@ItzWarty

Thanks for ReplyItzWarty....

I simply put this function on Onload event of the body.
But it simply deleted all the divs... my problem is not solved yet.

Comment: it also deleted parent node..
<div id="xlaANMzone_388e7f"><div class="" id="388e7f"><div class="media">
  <div class="wof">
    <a href="http://www.mychristiandaily.com/article.asp?a=1199&amp;Z=36" title="Pastor Rick Warren blinded in gardening accident">
      Pastor Rick Warren blinded in gardening accident
    </a>
     <span></span>
  </div>
  <a href="http://www.mychristiandaily.com/article.asp?a=1199&a
    
</div>

</div><div align="left"></div></div>

Comment: That's weird.  Can you give me an example webpage that shows this behavior?

Comment: http://www.mychristiandaily.com/index.asp

Use IE 7.It is giving extra div after every news item..

Thanks ItzWarty.

Comment: @ItzWarty.

The above snippet is removing parent node as the text is coming through ajax in the parent node after Document has been loaded.Ther child nodes are also loaded via ajax. Any Help Please.

Comment: You could wait for all xhr requests to be completed before calling the code.  In addition, you could mark nodes as "noclear" or something and check for that before detaching them from their parent nodes.